# How can I slide from top to bottom in a dataframe in R with different sliding window using tidyverse?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | -12 |
| 18 | -22 |
| 29 | -32 |
| 40 | -42 |
| 51 | -52 |

I want to slide from top to bottom with:

sliding window 3 :

7 -22 = -15

7 -32 = -25

18 -42 = -24

29 -52 = -23

40 -52 = -12

from this calculations I want R to report me the minimum which is -25.

for sliding window 5  :

7-32 =-25

7-42 = -35

7 -52  = -45

18 -52  =-34

29-52 =-23

and R to report me -45.

How can I do this in R ?

```
library(tidyverse)
a = c(7,18,29,40,51)
b = c(-12,-22,-32,-42,-52)
w = tibble(a,b);w
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(b3 = lead(b, default = last(b)), 
   a3= lag(a, default = first(a)), 
   b_a = b3 + a3, 
   b5 = lead(b, n = 2, default = last(b)),
   a5 = lag(a,n = 2, default = first(a)), b_a_5 = b5 + a5) %>%
   summarise(out1 = min(b_a), out2 = min(b_a_5))
```

-output

```
 out1 out2
1  -25  -45
```

Comment: can you do it using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74018046/how-can-i-rollapply-in-r-with-two-columns-of-a-data-frame/74018648#74018648) ?

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson that can be done, but from your input/expected output, it seems to be lagging or leading the column values instead of windowing

Comment: I would appreciate it if you do it with slice_dfr.I see the lagging issue.You ae right.But  if you can do it I would it will be great.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson the issue is also that you are doing this in reverse i.e. for 'a', it is lag' and 'b' it is lead.  In that other question, I used sequence to index and that is common for both the columns.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson in addition, your example is not doing windowing.  So, why you want slide i.e. suppose you do `seq_len(nrow(df1)) %>% slide(~ .x, .after = 3, .complete = TRUE)`, you will get the index in a list i.e. first list element gets 1 to 4 rows, and second, 2:5

Comment: I see you are right

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Do you want `Filter(length,  seq_len(nrow(df1)) %>% slide(~ lead(df1$b[.x], default = last(df1$b)) + lag(df1$a[.x], default = first(df1$a)), .after = 3, .complete = TRUE))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248884/discussion-between-homer-jay-simpson-and-akrun).

Answer (score 3):

For the first step

```
w = w |> 
  mutate(
    sw3 = lag(a, 1L, default = first(a))  + lead(b, 1L, default = last(b)),
    sw5 = lag(a, 2L, default = first(a))  + lead(b, 2L, default = last(b))  
  )
#       a     b   sw3   sw5
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     7   -12   -15   -25
# 2    18   -22   -25   -35
# 3    29   -32   -24   -45
# 4    40   -42   -23   -34
# 5    51   -52   -12   -23
```

To find the lowest value:

```
lapply(select(w, sw3, sw5), min)
# $sw3
# [1] -25

# $sw5
# [1] -45
```

Or

```
map_dbl(select(w, sw3, sw5), min)
# sw3 sw5 
# -25 -45
```